# Do we need the Private Beta help?

Tags: support, help-center

Right now, there's an interesting page on the Help Center: [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask-beta).

As Ask Ubuntu is not really in private beta anymore, is this page really necessary? Or, more accurately, is there a valid reason for keeping this help page around?

Comment: Forgot to add that the valid reason is that the help center describes SE in general (see "our model" etc) as well as AU in particular, so it makes sense to have that there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (I asked an SE dev), it's always been there. We'd just never noticed before the recent snafu. Obviously, we've long since memorized everything in the help center and don't visit often anymore or we'd have seen it ;)

As I understand, the help centers of all sites are copied from http://meta.stackexchange.com and then overwritten by local content, if any. Since that page is also [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) on the main meta.SE help, it's safe to assume it's always been in ours as well.

Comment: "Always been there" is good to know. I've checked a few other SE sites, and find it there as well. That said, can it actually be removed? If not, then that is a "valid" reason to keep it. If it can be removed, should it be removed? (2¢ I'd think removal is a good choice.)

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver why would we want to remove it? Beta sites are part of the SE model and the help center is both for specific AU stuff and general SE stuff. Why would we remove useful information?

Comment: If the Help Center content is copied from MSE, one time, and then overwritten by local content, then for AU, and other established sites, the Private Beta help is no longer "usefull." If it's copied and overwritten dynamically, then it would have to stay so that it's available for the sites that still are in private beta. As the OP said, AU isn't in private beta anymore. Your comment to the Q explains how the Help Center is both local and SE-wide help, so keeping it make sense. If I was the OP, that would be the accepted answer, short as it is.